Docker service fails to start because networks have same bridge name
I'm using Arch linux (6.10.3-arch1-2) and the docker (version 27.1.1). When I try to start the docker service using sudo systemctl start docker it fails with following error message:
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xeu docker.service" for details.

Following is the result of journalctl -xeu docker.service
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.208271655+05:45" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-3277f527c7c3 already part of docker zone, returning"
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.308953466+05:45" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-4cf0aac9698e already part of docker zone, returning"
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.318446672+05:45" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-4cf0aac9698e already part of docker zone, returning"
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.432143973+05:45" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-714634a808e0 already part of docker zone, returning"
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.441724619+05:45" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-714634a808e0 already part of docker zone, returning"
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.536105654+05:45" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-92e5cce94819 already part of docker zone, returning"
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.545116899+05:45" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-92e5cce94819 already part of docker zone, returning"
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.638299279+05:45" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-e709bec9fb16 already part of docker zone, returning"
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.647816162+05:45" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface br-e709bec9fb16 already part of docker zone, returning"
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.759571855+05:45" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface docker0 already part of docker zone, returning"
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.769116534+05:45" level=info msg="Firewalld: interface docker0 already part of docker zone, returning"
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.852703463+05:45" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0/16. Daemon option --bip can be used to set a preferred IP address"
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.853900162+05:45" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error creating default "bridge" network: cannot create network 7cd124dff3d618d064fc16c31560594e00c660e7f70ed40187d4e399e8a05be1 (docker0): conflicts with network f1a640266993e1b9c413a10e0a721f67025e44a92235ecf9d683714a9076f586 (docker0): networks have same bridge name
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift dockerd[6801]: time="2024-08-09T19:51:10.854143901+05:45" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit docker.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 09 19:51:10 rift systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.

I tried to follow the steps mentioned in this post but any of the solution mentioned there didn't work.
